# How can one modify a scoped variable from inside a function?

Tags: c++, function

This is in C++ (Eclipse Mars, if it matters, compiler MinGW). Let's say that I want to split a string into two strings on a character, and use a function:

```
int strParse(const string& a) {
    // parse line read input
    int b = a.find("-");
    firstsplit = a.substr(0, b);
    secsplit = a.substr(b + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

But I'd like to define `firstsplit` and `secsplit` not as global variables but within the scope of `main()` that they're used. When they're defined there, they can't be used in the function, but I need the function to define them for use in part of `main`.

Comment: @Why if you define the variables in `main` can't be used in the function (implying that you pass them as arguments of course)?

Comment: You either need to pass the strings into the function so you can populate them or you need to pass them out of the function in something like a pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly define them in `main()` and pass them by reference. But that's sloppy.

If you were to analyze this situation, `firstsplit` and `secsplit` are what your function calculates.

Therefore, what your function should do is return these values. This is what a function is all about: it calculates something, and returns it.

One way to do that would be to simply return a `std::pair`.

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> strParse(const string& a) { //parse line read input
    int b = a.find("-");
    std::string firstsplit = a.substr(0, b);
    std::string secsplit = a.substr(b + 1);
    return std::make_pair(firstsplit, secsplit);
}
```

But this would result in more work, and more rewriting if your function also might need to return something else, or some other alternative result, such as an error indication.

The most flexible approach is for the function to return a class:

```
class parse_results {

public:

     std::string firstsplit;
     std::string secsplit;
};

parse_results strParse(const string& a) { //parse line read input
    parse_results ret;

    int b = a.find("-");
    ret.firstsplit = a.substr(0, b);
    ret.secsplit = a.substr(b + 1);
    return ret;
}
```

Then, if you need to have any kind of additional information returned here, this can simply be added to the `parse_results` class.

Comment: Such a nice example(upvoted). Personally, I would use a `vector<string>` as a return type because he could possible return more than 2 strings.

Comment: @KostasRim I would not.  As is or if the OP uses a `std::tuple` will allow them to use structured bindings when that comes out in C++17.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not familiar with C++17 additions, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I would also use `struct` rather than `class{ public... `, since the whole thing is just a data aggregate. I might even use an anonymous `struct` with `auto` return-type.

Comment: ....But mostly I feel bad for typing up an inferior answer on a smartphone while you wrote this.

Comment: Why would I need to `return ret`? What does that change? Can't I just declare it as `int strParse` and `return 0`?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg No. The ***whole point*** of this answer is that the function performs the parsing and *returns* the parsed substrings.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to declare the two `std::string` in main and then pass them as arguments to the function. If that's not the behavior you are looking for, you can instead make the function return a `std::vector<string>`.

I would like to point out that `string::find()` method returns `size_t` and not an `int`.  If you are unsure of a type you can always use `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

try 
int strParse(const string& a, string& firstsplit, string& secsplit)

Comment: No idea why `downvote` on this. But I guess it's because of the lack of expnation.

Comment: @sjsam No explanation and poor formatting look like good reasons to down vote.(not the down voter)

Answer (score 0):

Your `int` return value is useless; it's always 0. Instead, simply return the two strings in a two-element `struct` or `std::array`.